Strongswan: only android client can connect to server but no internet access
I'm a beginner in the Strongswan. I set up the StrongSwan and IKEv2 on ubuntu. And it is working great. Some android client(samsung galaxy) can connect to server but no internet access. Other devices are working well.(ios, windows etc..). Please help me solve the problem:) Thank you
/etc/ipsec.conf
config setup
charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
uniqueids=replace

conn ikev2-vpn
auto=add
compress=no
type=tunnel
keyexchange=ikev2
fragmentation=yes
forceencaps=yes
dpdaction=clear
dpddelay=150s
rekey=no
left=%any
leftid=@my domain
leftcert=server-cert.pem
leftsendcert=always
leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
right=%any
rightid=%any
rightauth=eap-mschapv2
rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
rightdns=1.1.1.1
rightsendcert=never
eap_identity=%identity
ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048,chacha20poly1305-sha512-curve25519-prfsha512,aes256gcm16-sha384-prfsha384-ecp384,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
esp=aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,chacha20poly1305-sha512,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!

/etc/ufw/before.rules
# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o enp2s0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE                                                                              
COMMIT
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
*mangle  
-A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
COMMIT

*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]

-A ufw-before-forward --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in --proto esp -s 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
# End required lines

/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf
net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
net/ipv6/ip_forward=1

net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects=0
net/ipv4/ip_no_pmtu_disc=1
net/ipv4/conf/default/accept_redirects=0

net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/all/send_redirects=0
net/ipv6/ip_no_pmtu_disc=1
net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_redirects=0

